# Splitting a string that contains some digits into multiple arrays of digits

Tags: c, arrays, function, return-value

I'm asking users to enter a string of that contains both digits, underscore and comma in MAIN function.

I'm creating a **function**, which will split the string into multiple arrays (using comma as separator).

For instance, if a user enters:

**"20_30_4_50, 6_7_80_90,11_22_3_44\n"**

I want to split, the string from the user into a three sets of arrays casted to integers - using the underscore to determine each value.

set1[size] = {**20, 30, 4, 50**};

set2[size] = {**6, 7, 80, 90**};

set3[size] = {**11, 22, 3, 44**};

After that, I want to **return this new arrays from this function** to the MAIN function.

The problem and what I have tried is:

1). I don't know how to add two strings (that are digits) together.

I tried **s[0]** i.e **string 2** PLUS **s[1]** i.e **string 0.**

*BUT IT DIDN'T PRODUCE 20 AS I EXPECTED*.

I need to join then before adding it to the new array.

2). I don't know how to return 3 sets of array from a single function.

Maybe a 2 dimensional array could work here.

HERE'S MY CODE BELOW (NB: I'm just starting in C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int arr(string sarr);
int main() {
    char s[100] = "20_30_4_50, 6_7_80_90,11_22_3_44"
    
    arr(s); //calling the function
    return 0;
}

int arr(string sarr)
{
    int len = strlen(sarr);
    int coma_count = 0, coma_pos[5], c_pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (sarr[i] = ",")
        {
      //count the no. of coma separated values.
            coma_count += 1; 
     //store position of each coma in an array.
            coma_pos[c_pos] = i;
        }
        if else(isdigit(sarr[len]))
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
    
    int index = 0, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coma_pos[0] - 1; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(sarr[i]) && isdigit(sarr[i + 1]) && sarr[i - 1] is not a digit)
        {
            newArr[count][index] = sarr[i] + sarr[i + 1]; //Won't work 
            index += 1;
        }
        
        else if (isdigit(sarr[i]) && sarr[i + 1] IS NOT A DIGIT && sarr[i - 1] IS NOT A DIGIT)
        {
            newArr[count][index] = sarr[i];
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    return //the new array to main    
}
```

Comment: "...I want to return this new arrays from this function...": You cannot return an array in C, unless the array is embedded in a struct or union. But you can return a pointer to the first element of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That is a little bit complicated to do in C (will be shown in my code below), you can't just add strings like in Python or other languages.
2. I believe you are not familiar with a concept of pointers yet, so the only way you can do it now is to pass arrays as arguments to a function, as I did below.

Here's one solution, not the best perhaps (I coded it really quickly), but it's fine for your current level:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arr(char sarr[], int set1[], int set2[], int set3[]);
void print_fun(int set1[], int set2[], int set3[]);

int main() {
    char s[100] = "20_30_4_50,6_7_80_90,11_22_3_44";
    int set1[20],set2[20],set3[20];

    arr(s,set1,set2,set3);

    print_fun(set1,set2,set3);

    return 0;
}

void print_fun(int set1[], int set2[], int set3[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d ", set1[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d ", set2[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d ", set3[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int make_num(char string[])
{
    int len,num = 0;

    len = strlen(string);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        num = num*10 + (string[i] - '0');
    }

    return num;
}

void arr(char sarr[], int set1[], int set2[], int set3[])
{
    int len = strlen(sarr);
    int coma_count = 1, num_tmp, ind, new_arr_ind = 0;
    char tmp[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        ind = 0;

        while(sarr[i] != ',' && sarr[i] != '\0')
        {
            if(sarr[i] != '_')
            {
                tmp[ind++] = sarr[i];
            }

            else
            {
                tmp[ind] = '\0';
                num_tmp = make_num(tmp);

                switch(coma_count)
                {
                    case 1:
                        set1[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        set2[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        set3[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                        break;
                }

                ind = 0;
                new_arr_ind++;
            }

            i++;
        }
        tmp[ind] = '\0';
        num_tmp = make_num(tmp);

        switch(coma_count)
        {
            case 1:
                set1[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                break;

            case 2:
                set2[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                break;

            case 3:
                set3[new_arr_ind] = num_tmp;
                break;
        }

        coma_count++;
        new_arr_ind = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Majki, I appreciate your comment and time. But please, could you explain what the for loop in make_num function is doing as it iterate from 0 to < Len. (i.e the num*10 part).     And secondly in the arr function I don't get the action of the second switch statement (it seems to perform the same function as the first inside else-block).  Tia.

Comment: You're welcome!

1) To make_num function, we send numbers as string ("20\0" for example), strlen is 2.  num = num*10 + (string[i] - '0'); line inside is how we actually make an intiger from a string. Num*10 is actually a weight of a digit (which is 10 in decimal number system). String[i] - '0' is how we convert char to int through ascii values ('2' = 62, '0' = 60 => 62-60 = 2). In the first iteration of our example, num = 0 (num = 0*10+2 = 2), and second num = 2*10+0

Comment: 2) This could be done better but I didn't have enough time, the second switch is there because while loop will break when sarr[i] != ',', but won't load the lust number, so we have to use it again outside for the last number before ','. Try to delete it and see what happens. You could also try to resolve it in a better way, using do while loop or some other idea.

Comment: Feel free to ask if I need to clarify even more.

Comment: Now, I get. Thanks. I'll try it later

Answer (score 3):

Are you writing C or C++ ?
If you are writing C then the string datatype doesn't exist, so you have to use char arrays defined like this:

```
char array[25];
```

Also at this statement `if (sarr[i] = ",")` you are making an assignment, not a comparison the correct form is this:

```
if (sarr[i] == ',')
```

note that i'm using single quotes, that's necessary if you want to compare characters.

On the second part in this line `newArr[count][index] = sarr[i] + sarr[i + 1];` you are trying to add strings with each other inside an array that doesn't exist.

Start by creating a new array or converting sarr's contents to integers, then define the newArr (I don't think you defined it) and it should work.